# How to intercept service-to-service call in Fiddler2?

Tags: .net, wcf, debugging, fiddler

On my Windows 7 machine, I have two web applications (which host WCF services) are hosted under IIS 7.5.

In Fiddler, I can see all the calls from my desktop application to the web application. However, I do not see any call from one service to another or one service calling some other website over internet.

**How to make Fiddler intercept service-to-service (internet service too) call?**

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-IIS

Answer (score 1):

Configure fiddler as a proxy in your Internet Explorer - this will make the settings global for whole machine (Fiddler can do that automatically if you allow it in settings).

Next try to capture traffic (make sure that you are capturing traffic from all processes). If you still don't see traffic from your services check:

- That you use external address when call service from client. When client calls services or sites deployed on your local machines client must call the service with your IP address or computer name. You must not use localhost / 127.0.0.1 - these calls are never proxied
- That you do not have any proxy bypass addresses configured in IE or bypass of local addresses checked
- That you do not overwrite proxy settings in your application - for example by turning off `useDefaultWebProxy` in WCF binding configuration or by setting proxy in `system.net` configuration.

As last you can try to add this to your client configurations (but this is default configuration):

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
</system.net>
```

By default you will see only HTTP traffic. HTTPS will require additional configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it did not solve my problem. I could not get how can i set 'Fiddler as a proxy' in IE. But I checked everything else you suggested. I am running WCF web applications under `NETWORK SERVICE` account. Could you guide me further?

Comment: I have the same scenario, i.e web app calls service 1 which calls service 2. Service 1 calls are being logged but not service 2. Service 1 is on my machine (using machine name alias as recommended) and service 2 is on another machine.